# 404 Not Found:The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: mysql, spring, gradle, model-view-controller

> This is the error I am getting I am using Gradle as build tool I have tried all the solutions 
>     on internet

```
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.27
 Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2019 09:57:22 UTC
 Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.27.0
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            5.0.0-32-generic
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Private Build
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         
/home/sudarshan/work/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/sudarshan/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.27
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - 
Dcatalina.base=/home/sudarshan/work/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/sudarshan/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.27
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - 
Dwtp.deploy=/home/sudarshan/work/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/
 wtpwebapps
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/sudarshan/Downloads/apache-tomcat- 
  9.0.27/endorsed
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in 
production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
[/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2016"]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [549] milliseconds
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for 
this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. 
Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class 
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache
(DefaultInstanceManager.java:402)
at 

org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance
(DefaultInstanceManager.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance
(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4607)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute
(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute
    (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryReference
    at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    ... 37 more

Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate 
container log file
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/HibernateTemplate] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for 
this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. 
Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader 
initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:37 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext 
prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Oct 24 15:01:37 IST 2019]; 
root of context hierarchy
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader 
loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-core- 
 config.xml]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader 
initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 188 ms
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcherServlet'
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcherServlet': initialization started
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext 
 prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcherServlet-servlet': 
startup date [Thu Oct 24 15:01:38 IST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader 
loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc- 
 config.xml]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping 
registerHandler
INFO: Root mapping to handler 'homeController'
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 425 ms
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2016"]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2019 3:01:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [2,794] milliseconds
```

> This is my build.gradle where I have added required dependencies

```
plugins {
// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
id 'java-library'
id 'war'
id 'org.gretty' version '2.3.1'
}

 repositories {

    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile 
 classpath.
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

// This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile 
classpath.
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.13.RELEASE'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.14.RELEASE'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.13'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'





// Use JUnit test framework
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

> This is my spring-core-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
xsi:schemaLocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    </beans>
```

> This is my spring-mvc-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
xsi:schemaLocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  

 <context:component-scan base-package="HibernateTemplate"></context:component-scan>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">    
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>    
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb"></property>    
<property name="username" value="root"></property>    
<property name="password" value="password"></property>    
</bean>    

<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">    
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>    
</bean>    

<bean id="dao" class="HibernateTemplate.StudentDao">    
<property name="template" ref="jt"></property>    
</bean>


</beans>
```

> This is my  web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- 
app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>web application</display-name>
<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all 
 application requests -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->

   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-core-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 </web-app>
```

> This is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="empform">Add Employee</a>  
<!-- <a href="viewemp">View Employees</a>  -->  
</body>
</html>
```

> studform.jsp file where I have created form to take values.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="empform">Add Employee</a>  
  <!-- <a href="viewemp">View Employees</a>  -->  
</body>
</html>
```

> index.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="empform">Add Employee</a>  
  <!-- <a href="viewemp">View Employees</a>  -->  
</body>
</html>
```

> Student.java class

```
package HibernateTemplate;

public class Student {

private int id;
private String name;
private String email;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


}
```

> StudentController class

```
package HibernateTemplate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import HibernateTemplate.Student;
import HibernateTemplate.StudentDao;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

@Autowired

StudentDao dao;

/*It displays a form to input data, here "command" is a reserved request attribute  
 which is used to display object data into form   */   

@RequestMapping("/studform")    
public String showform(Model m){    
    m.addAttribute("command", new Student());  
    return "studform";   
}

/*It saves object into database. The @ModelAttribute puts request data into model object. 
 *You need to mention RequestMethod.POST method   
  because default request is GET*/    

@RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String save(@ModelAttribute("std") Student std){    
    dao.save(std);    
    return "save"; //will redirect to viewemp request mapping    
}   

}
```

> StudentDao class

```
package HibernateTemplate;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class StudentDao {

    JdbcTemplate template; 

    public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {    
        this.template = template;    
    }  

    public int save(Student s){    
        String sql="insert into student(id,name,email) 
        values('"+s.getId()+"',"+s.getName()+",'"+s.getEmail()+"')";    
        return template.update(sql);   
    } 

}
```

> I just needs to connect with database so that I can go ahead and do further operations, also 
>     you can recommend me book where I can learn spring MVC using gradle as there is no gradle 
>     stuff available on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by removing this from `<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>` from `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">`. I think this unnecessarily used. This may cause problem.

Updated bean should look like this :

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Now it's showing:WARNING: No mapping for GET /HibernateTemplate/[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5a2d131d]